# List of list (or dictionary) in R

Tags: r, list

I have a dataframe such as :

```
Groups Letters
G1   A
G1   A
G1   A
G1   A
G2   B
G2   B
G3   C
G3   C
G3   C
G4   A
G4   A
G5   C
```

and I would like to parse the dataframe and create a list of list that I can interogate.

so in fact I would like to print the Groups for each name within this list such as :

**list$A**
gives  :

```
['G1','G4']
```

Does someone have an idea please ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `split` the 'Groups' by 'Letters' on the `unique` dataset (assuming only two columns or else subset the selected columns), loop over the `list` and convert to nested list with `as.list`

```
lapply(with(unique(df1), split(Groups, Letters)), as.list)
```

-output

```
$A
$A[[1]]
[1] "G1"

$A[[2]]
[1] "G4"


$B
$B[[1]]
[1] "G2"


$C
$C[[1]]
[1] "G3"

$C[[2]]
[1] "G5"
```

---

If the OP wanted to create a string,

```
lapply(with(unique(df1), split(Groups, Letters)), 
      function(x) sprintf("[%s]", toString(sQuote(x, FALSE))))
```

-output

```
$A
[1] "['G1', 'G4']"

$B
[1] "['G2']"

$C
[1] "['G3', 'G5']"
```

---

Or probably, we can convert to JSON

```
library(jsonlite)
lapply(with(unique(df1), split(Groups, Letters)), function(x) toJSON(x))
$A
["G1","G4"] 

$B
["G2"] 

$C
["G3","G5"]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Groups = c("G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", 
"G3", "G3", "G3", "G4", "G4", "G5"), Letters = c("A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A", "A", "C")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: how can I for instance just say : ```li$A``` and get the list of Groups such as : ```['G1','G4']```

Comment: @chippycentra i read your question as you wanted a list inside i.e. `out$A
[[1]]
[1] "G1"

[[2]]
[1] "G4"`.  The one you showed seems to python list

Comment: yes sorry for that, I made it not clear enough, let me edit the post ...

Comment: @chippycentra does the update works for you or are you looking to create python list within R

Comment: @chippycentra it is not clear about the structure you want.  My solution is basically based on what you showed.  it could be a string or a json list.  It is difficult to differentiate from what you showed

Comment: The json solution gives the solution as perfect ! thanks you very much for your help

Comment: @chippycentra i thought you were doing some parsing into python.  so json would be the better one

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `tapply` could help

```
with(
  df,
  tapply(Groups, Letters, FUN = function(v) as.list(unique(v)))
)
```

which gives

```
$A
$A[[1]]
[1] "G1"

$A[[2]]
[1] "G4"


$B
$B[[1]]
[1] "G2"


$C
$C[[1]]
[1] "G3"

$C[[2]]
[1] "G5"
```